# How do I update CiviCRM on wordpress? ( currently on 5.38.0 )

Tags: wordpress, upgrade

I am using a very outdated version of CiviCRM ( 5.38.0 ) and I'm totally clueless with how to update it.

It says system status is critical and that I should upgrade to latest version (5.71.1 ), but it just links me to download a zip folder from their website and I have no idea what to do form there as I'm finding the instructions too complicated. Can you help me in simple, easy to follow instruction?

It also says cron is not running and i'm unsure how to run it...

Comment: Do you want to get in touch with me on pradpnayak at gmail dot com, i can help you to upgrade your site with no charge

Answer (score 0):

You can find details of how to upgrade in the SysAdmin guide:

https://docs.civicrm.org/sysadmin/en/latest/upgrade/wordpress/