# Updating from CiviCRM 5.38.0. to 5.71 on wordpress

Tags: wordpress, upgrade, installation

Any help with how to update CiviCRM 5.38.0. to 5.71 on wordpress?

Currently my website says--> System Status: Critical  (which is obviously quite worrying!)
I've downloaded the zip file from civiCRM but I'm stuck on the next step...
Simple instructions would be greatly appreciated,as I'm not a tech pro.

Comment: would you like to get in touch on https://chat.civicrm.org/civicrm/messages/@pradpnayak will do it for you with no charge

Comment: This appears to be a duplicate of https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/47666/how-do-i-update-civicrm-on-wordpress-currently-on-5-38-0

Answer (score 0):

You can find details of how to upgrade in the SysAdmin guide:

https://docs.civicrm.org/sysadmin/en/latest/upgrade/

Answer (score 0):

If you do not have anything custom, simply delete the old Civi folder, purge the templates_c in the Uploads folder and then go here:

https://example.org/wp-admin/admin.php?page=CiviCRM&q=civicrm/upgrade&reset=1

I have a the CiviCRM Admin Utilities plugin and does wonders as it automates a lot of stuff. You can trigger the Clean Cache, Rebuild on the fly, and trigger the upgrade there, as well.

**ALWAYS BACK UP!**